# How to check if a given pathname matches a given regular expression in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to figure a way out to compare each directory path against a given regular expression to find out if it matches that pattern or not.

I have the following list of paths

```
C:\Dir
C:\Dir\data
C:\Dir\data\file1
C:\Dir\data\file2
C:\Dir\data\match1\file1
C:\Dir\data\match1\file2
```

I only want to print those paths that match the following pattern
where "*" can replace zero or more directory levels and *match1* can be either the name of a file or directory.

```
C:\Dir\*\match1
```

I figured out that re.match() would help me out with this but I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to define the pattern and the one I came up with (pasted below) doesn't work at all. *item* will contain the path in quotes

```
re.match("((C:\\)(Dir)\\(.*)\\(match1))",item)
```

Can someone please help me out with this task ?

Comment: Actually the `*` part is not a *regex*.

Comment: Have a look at the following post. I think it should help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43096014/search-for-any-number-of-unknown-substrings-in-place-of-in-a-list-of-string/43096243#43096243

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go for:

```
^C:\\Dir\\.+?match1.*
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/AKwdyw/2).

---

In `Python`, this would be:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'C:\\Dir\\.+?match1.*')

files = [r'C:\Dir', r'C:\Dir\data', r'C:\Dir\data\file1', r'C:\Dir\data\file2', r'C:\Dir\data\match1\file1', r'C:\Dir\data\match1\file2']

filtered = [match.group(0) 
            for file in files 
            for match in [rx.match(file)] 
            if match]

print(filtered)
```

Or, if you like `filter()` and `lambda()`:

```
filtered = list(filter(lambda x: rx.match(x), files))
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Jan, your expression did the trick with one slight modification, C:\\Dir\\.+?match1.* is the pattern I wanted. It has to match at any level which also includes C:\Dir\match1. This path wouldn't be matched by .+ :)

Comment: @DhiwakarRavikumar: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your regexp is:

```
^C:\\Dir\\.*match1
```

Explanation is:

`C:\\Dir\\` is start sub string of your path

`.*` any other symbols in path

`match1` explicit name of something that goes after (file or dir)

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have yet reputation to comment, I'll remark here.

The solution proposed by @Jan works for the particular list of paths in question, but has a few problems if applied as a general solution. If list of paths is as follows:

```
>>> print paths
C:\Dir
C:\Dir\data
C:\Dir\match1
C:\Dir\data\file1
C:\Dir\data\match1\file1
C:\Dir\data\match1\file2
C:\Dir\data\abcmatch1def\file3
C:\Dir\data\file1\match12
C:\Dir\data\file1\match1
>>>
```

the (r'C:\Dir\.+?match1.*') fails to match "C:\Dir\match1" and produces false positives, i.e. "C:\Dir\data\abc**match1**def\file3" and "C:\Dir\data\file1\**match1**2".

Proposed solution:

```
>>> import re
>>> for line in paths.splitlines():
...     if re.match(r"C:\\Dir.*\\match1(\\|$)", line):
...             print line
...
C:\Dir\match1
C:\Dir\data\match1\file1
C:\Dir\data\match1\file2
C:\Dir\data\file1\match1
>>>
```